# not getting correct date for displaying yesterday's date

Tags: php, mysql, date

when giving `curr_date='2019/07/02'` its working,but when giving `curr_date='$b'` not working

```php
$b = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("yesterday"));

$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM tbl_order_item 
        WHERE item_selected ='liquor' 
          and curr_time  BETWEEN '17:00:00' AND '24:00:00' 
          AND '1:00:00' 
          and item_name LIKE 'd%' 
          and curr_date='$b'";
```

Comment: `BETWEEN` doesn't take 3 arguments. I formatted your query, see how `AND '1:00:00'` gets a separate condition?

Comment: What is the data-type of  `curr_date`? Datetime? Date?

Comment: add this and curr_date='".$b."'";

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `-` dash in your `$b = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("yesterday"));` use `/` slash

Also **Modify the BETWEEN clause because it takes only two values** e.g

```
$b=date("Y/m/d",strtotime("yesterday")); # see here Y/m/d

$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_order_item WHERE item_selected ='liquor' and  
curr_time  BETWEEN '17:00:00' AND '24:00:00' and item_name  
LIKE 'd%' and curr_date='$b'";
```

Comment: Why would that work? The proper format is `YYYY-MM-DD`.